# Let $u$ and $w$ be complex numbers such that $|u|=5, |w|=3,$ and $|u+w|=6$. Calculate $|u+2w|$ with proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

This came up on my homework and I don't understand how to calculate $|u+2w|$. How do I get from $|u+w|$ to $|u+2w|$? I'm guessing that I have to square $|u+w|$ and then add $|u|$ and $|w|$ in a way that which would have a square root of $|u+2w|$ but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Draw and label a vector diagram of the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $|u+w|=6$. (eq. 1)

On squaring eq. 1, we get

$|u|^2+|w|^2+u\bar{w}+\bar{u}w=36$

$\implies u\bar{w}+\bar{u}w=36-25-9=2$ (eqn. 2)

Now, $|u+2w|^2=|u|^2+4|w|^2+2(u\bar{w}+\bar{u}w)=25+36+4=65$

Hence, $|u+2w|=\sqrt{65}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $~z = x + iy,~$ define $~\overline{z} = x - iy.$

This alternative approach is given in case the original poster has not learned that $~|u + w|^2 = |u|^2 + |w|^2 + u\overline{w} + \overline{u}w.$

In computing $~|u + 2w|,~$ what controls this value is the angle between $~u~$ and $~w.~$  So, you can assume, without loss of generality, that $~u = 5 + i(0),~$ and $~\displaystyle w = x \pm i\sqrt{9 - x^2}.~$

Therefore, you have that

$$6 = |u + w| = \sqrt{(5+x)^2 + (9 - x^2)} \implies $$

$$36 = (25 + 10x + x^2) + (9 - x^2) = 34 + 10x \implies x = \frac{1}{5} \implies $$

$$w = \frac{1}{5} \pm i\frac{\sqrt{224}}{5} \implies $$

$$u + 2w = \frac{27}{5} \pm 2i\frac{\sqrt{224}}{5} \implies $$

$$|u +  2w|^2 = \frac{1}{25} \left[ ~(27)^2 + 4(224) ~\right] = 65 \implies $$

$$|u + 2w| = \sqrt{65}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Clearly $|u+w|=6$, $|u|=5$ and $|w|=3$ indicate that $u\bar{w}+w\bar{u}=36-25-9=2$. Therefore $|u+2w|^2=|u|^2+4|w|^2+2u\bar{w}+2w\bar{u}=25+36+2\times2=65$ and so $|u+2w|=\sqrt{65}$.

Comment: $+\color{red}{4}|w|^2$

Comment: Please edit according to @Bob Dobbs 's remark